# Getting the current zoom of a powerpoint presentation

Tags: c#, .net, powerpoint, office-interop

I am trying to detect the current zoom of a powerpoint presentation. The following is the code I have just written:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application application = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application();
Presentation presentation = application.Presentations.Open(file_name);

application.Visible = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue;
if (document.SlideShowWindow.View.Zoom == 90) { blah }
```

I'm getting the following error and can't work out why:

```
An exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in ICTeacher.exe but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Presentation (unknown member) : Invalid request.  There is currently no slide show view for this presentation.
```

The line causing the error is `document.SlideShowWindow.View.Zoom == 90`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where are you getting the slideshowwindow?

Comment: @Jacobr365 I'm not, that's all the code dealing with powerpoint above. Have I missed something?

Comment: I haven't used office interop for powerpoint so just making educated guesses. But looking at other questions on zooming people seem to be created a slideshowwindow by setting up the presentation and calling run. Dont like typing putting lots of code in comments and this isnt good enough for an answer. https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/threads/162812/how-to-control-ms-powerpoint-2007-slide-show-using-c-3-5 Look there and pay attention to how they make the window. Around lines 13&14.

Comment: Until you put the presentation into slide show view, there's no SlideShowWindow, so any attempt to manipulate it or query its properties will fail.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg so how would I go about getting the zoom% the user currently has it set to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, I needed: `Application.ActiveWindow.View.Zoom` instead of `document.SlideShowWindow.View.Zoom`.